# Is it possible to have i18n without l10n?

Tags: i18n-l10n

What I mean by this is: Is it possible to have translated content* without having a translated interface?  Can we make the interface always be in English, even if I am translating content into Spanish?

* I'm use Entity Translation, but I imagine that this question would apply equally to i18n module.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to the preferred interface language in your user profile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could set English as the default language and hide the section mentioned by Volker in the user profile (hook_form_alter for example or by CSS).

Then in the Language -> Detection and selection screen (admin/config/regional/language/configure), set User as the first detection and selection method and for example URL as the second choice. This way anonymous users will follow the URL indication but the authenticated users will get the language defined in their language settings which should be the default language.

[image]